# LINQ join query to two tables with the same model

Tags: linq, join, linq2db

I have two tables in a database with the same structure.
The tables have many columns, the types and names are absolutely the same.
Let's say their names are OldTable and NewTable.
In my project I have one model for these tables.
I need to perform an inner join on tables.
When i try it i have SQL Query with the same table, for example:

```
Select column1 from OldTable oldData
Inner Join OldTable newData on oldData.Column1 = newData.Column1
```

What is wrong?

Sample code that i use:

```
var oldCtx = _oldDataSource.DataContext.Rows;
var newCtx = _newDataSource.DataContext.Rows;

var query = from oldData in oldCtx
            join newData in newCtx
            on new { oldData.Column1, oldData.Column2, oldData.Column3, oldData.Column4, oldData.Column5 }
            equals new { newData.Column1, newData.Column2, newData.Column3, newData.Column4, newData.Column5 }
            where oldData.StartTime >= dateStart && oldData.StartTime < dateStart + timeSpan
            select newData;

var newCdrs = query.ToList();
```

Result query is:

```
DECLARE @dateStart TimeStamp -- DateTime
SET     @dateStart = TIMESTAMP '2024-01-22 15:54:33.000000'
DECLARE @CallStartTime TimeStamp -- DateTime
SET     @CallStartTime = TIMESTAMP '2024-01-22 15:54:34.000000'

SELECT
    newData.Column1,
    newData.Column2,
    newData.Column3,
    newData.Column4,
    newData.Column5,
.....

FROM
    DEV3.OldTable  oldData
        INNER JOIN DEV3.OldTable newData ON (oldData.COLUMN1 = newData.COLUMN1 OR oldData.COLUMN1 IS NULL AND newData.COLUMN1 IS NULL) AND (oldData.COLUMN2 = newData.COLUMN2 OR oldData.COLUMN2 IS NULL AND newData.COLUMN2 IS NULL) AND (oldData.COLUMN3 = newData.COLUMN3 OR oldData.COLUMN3 IS NULL AND newData.COLUMN3 IS NULL) AND (oldData.COLUMN4 = newData.COLUMN4 OR oldData.COLUMN4 IS NULL AND newData.COLUMN4 IS NULL) AND (oldData.COLUMN5 = newData.COLUMN5 OR oldData.COLUMN5 IS NULL AND newData.COLUMN5 IS NULL)
WHERE
    oldData.START_TIME >= :dateStart AND oldData.START_TIME < :CallStartTime
```

But I expected `JOIN DEV3.NewTable`

Comment: Your definitions for oldCtx and newCtx are missing to make a judgement. Likely both are pointing to same table.

Comment: What is `_oldDataSource`, what is `DataContext`, what is `Rows`? Is there some sort of ORM involved here? If so, how did you map the tables?

Comment: Which ORM do you use? EF, linq2b, etc.

Comment: I use linq2db.   
_newDataSource.DataContext.Rows -> Table(DEV3.NEWTABLE)
_oldDataSource.DataContext.Rows -> Table(DEV3.OLDTABLE)

Comment: `
public sealed class DataContext<T> : DataConnection
    where T : class
{
    public DataContext(LinqToDBConnectionOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public ITable<T> Rows => this.GetTable<T>();
}
`

Comment: @CetinBasoz
I'am sure that newCtx and oldCtx pointing to different tables. 
Moreover, when i flip like that:
`
var query = from newData in newCtx
            join oldData in oldCtx
`
i got SQL query with different table:
`
FROM
    DEV3.NewTable  newData
        INNER JOIN DEV3.newTable oldData ON ...
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `linq2db` for such cases you can use `TableName`, `SchemaName`, `ServerName` extensions. They are defined for `ITable` interface.

```cs
var query = from oldData in oldCtx
            join newData in newCtx.TableName("NewData")
            on new { oldData.Column1, oldData.Column2, oldData.Column3, oldData.Column4, oldData.Column5 }
            equals new { newData.Column1, newData.Column2, newData.Column3, newData.Column4, newData.Column5 }
            where oldData.StartTime >= dateStart && oldData.StartTime < dateStart + timeSpan
            select newData;
```

Also for such queries, you do not need two DataContexts, one is enough.

```cs
var rows = _oldDataSource.DataContext.Rows;

var query = from oldData in rows
            join newData in rows.TableName("NewData")
            on new { oldData.Column1, oldData.Column2, oldData.Column3, oldData.Column4, oldData.Column5 }
            equals new { newData.Column1, newData.Column2, newData.Column3, newData.Column4, newData.Column5 }
            where oldData.StartTime >= dateStart && oldData.StartTime < dateStart + timeSpan
            select newData;
```